# Resolving overloaded float/double method variants from Clojure

Tags: types, clojure, overloading

[java.lang.Math.scalb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#scalb(double,%20int)) is overloaded to accept a double or a float value as the first parameter. I would like to call the double variant but I am converting from a clojure long. The only way I have found that resolves correctly is by coercing to a double, then calling the java.lang.Double constructor. Is there a less cluttered way of doing this?

```
user> (Math/scalb 21 -63)
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: scalb  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:80)

user> (Math/scalb (double 21) -63)
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one matching method found: scalb, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1) 

user> (Math/scalb (Double. 21) -63)
IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found for class java.lang.Double  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor (Reflector.java:183)

user> (Math/scalb (Double. (double 21)) -63)
2.2768245622195593E-18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the second argument too: it's an int argument, but your numbers are longs. Obviously the compiler *could* figure it out in some cases (such as this one), but once you start providing typehints you're expected to finish disambiguating.

```
user> (Math/scalb (double 21) (int -63))
2.2768245622195593E-18
```